# conditional update/insert in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure for updating/inserting data being read from XML. Now as you see in the xml data under itemResults, there are multiple (2 in this case) items. I want that only the item for which the values are changed should be updated. In my stored procedure it takes the value of the first item by default. The item value will obviously be changed at runtime. Similarly whatever no. of items are added by the user (in case of new items being added), they should be saved to the database.

The XML DATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SaveOrder xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<OrderID>10511</OrderID>
<RowID>0</RowID>
<EmployeeID>0</EmployeeID>
<OrderDate>4/18/1997</OrderDate>
<ShipVia>0</ShipVia>
<Freight>0</Freight>
<ContactName>Laurence Lebihan</ContactName>
<Phone>91.24.45.40</Phone>
<ItemCount>0</ItemCount>

<orderResults>
<Orders>
<OrderID>10511</OrderID>
<RowID>68</RowID>
<CustomerID>BONAP</CustomerID>
<EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>
<OrderDate>4/18/1997</OrderDate>
<RequiredDate>5/16/1997</RequiredDate>
<ShippedDate>5/16/1997</ShippedDate>
<ShipVia>3</ShipVia>
<Freight>420</Freight>
<ShipName>Bon app'</ShipName>
<ShipAddress>12, rue des Bouchers</ShipAddress>
<ShipCity>Marseille</ShipCity>
<ShipRegion />
<ShipPostalCode>13008</ShipPostalCode>
<ShipCountry>France</ShipCountry>
<CompanyName>Bon app'</CompanyName>
<ContactName>Laurence Lebihan</ContactName>
<Phone>91.24.45.40</Phone>
<ItemCount>3</ItemCount>

<itemResults>
<Items>
<OrderID>10511</OrderID>
<ProductID>4</ProductID>
<UnitPrice>22.0000</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>50</Quantity>
<Discount>0.15</Discount>
</Items>
<Items>
<OrderID>10511</OrderID>
<ProductID>7</ProductID>
<UnitPrice>30.0000</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>50</Quantity>
<Discount>0.15</Discount>
</Items>
<Items>
<OrderID>10511</OrderID>
<ProductID>8</ProductID>
<UnitPrice>40.0000</UnitPrice>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
<Discount>0.15</Discount>

</Items>
</itemResults>
</Orders>
</orderResults>
</SaveOrder>
```

The Stored Procedure:
       ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdateOrderDetail]

```
   @Request XML = '<Request/>'--, 
--@Response XML = '<Response/>' OUTPUT

   As

   BEGIN
DECLARE @OrderID int
DECLARE @ProductID nvarchar(50)

SET @OrderID = @Request.value('(SaveOrder/OrderID)[1]', 'int') 
IF @OrderID > 0 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE  Customers SET 
                ContactName = T.C.value('(ContactName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(30)'),
                Phone = T.C.value('(Phone/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(24)')
                --OrderDate = T.C.value('OrderDate[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        FROM @Request.nodes('/SaveOrder/orderResults/Orders') as T(C)
        WHERE CustomerID = T.C.value('(CustomerID/text())[1]', 'nchar(5)')

        UPDATE  Orders SET 
                OrderDate = T.C.value('(OrderDate/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
                RequiredDate = T.C.value('(RequiredDate/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
                ShippedDate = T.C.value('(ShippedDate/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
                ShipVia = T.C.value('(ShipVia/text())[1]', 'int'),
                Freight = T.C.value('(Freight/text())[1]', 'money'),
                ShipName = T.C.value('(ShipName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(40)'),
                ShipAddress = T.C.value('(ShipAddress/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(60)'),
                ShipCity = T.C.value('(ShipCity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(15)'),
                ShipRegion = T.C.value('(ShipRegion/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(15)'),
                ShipPostalCode = T.C.value('(ShipPostalCode/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)'),
                ShipCountry = T.C.value('(ShipCountry/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(15)')

        FROM @Request.nodes('/SaveOrder/orderResults/Orders') as T(C)
        WHERE OrderID = @OrderID

        UPDATE  [Order Details] SET 
                UnitPrice = T.C.value('(UnitPrice/text())[1]', 'money'),
                Quantity = T.C.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'smallint'),
                Discount = T.C.value('(Discount/text())[1]', 'real')

        FROM @Request.nodes('/SaveOrder/orderResults/Orders/itemResults/Items') as T(C)
        WHERE OrderID = @OrderID
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Customers
                    (ContactName,
                        Phone)  

        SELECT   T.C.value('(ContactName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(30)'),
                 T.C.value('(Phone/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(24)')

        FROM @Request.nodes('/SaveOrder/orderResults/Orders') as T(C)


        INSERT INTO Orders(
                OrderDate, 
                RequiredDate, 
                ShippedDate ,
                ShipVia ,
                Freight ,
                ShipName ,
                ShipAddress ,
                ShipCity ,
                ShipRegion ,
                ShipPostalCode ,
                ShipCountry )

        SELECT  T.C.value('(OrderDate/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
                 T.C.value('(RequiredDate/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
                 T.C.value('(ShippedDate/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
                 T.C.value('(ShipVia/text())[1]', 'int'),
                 T.C.value('(Freight/text())[1]', 'money'),
                 T.C.value('(ShipName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(40)'),
                 T.C.value('(ShipAddress/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(60)'),
                 T.C.value('(ShipCity/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(15)'),
                T.C.value('(ShipRegion/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(15)'),
                T.C.value('(ShipPostalCode/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)'),
                 T.C.value('(ShipCountry/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(15)')

        FROM @Request.nodes('/SaveOrder/orderResults/Orders') as T(C)

        INSERT INTO [Order Details]
                    (UnitPrice ,
                    Quantity,
                    Discount)

        SELECT  T.C.value('(UnitPrice/text())[1]', 'money'),
                T.C.value('(Quantity/text())[1]', 'smallint'),
                T.C.value('(Discount/text())[1]', 'real')

        FROM @Request.nodes('/SaveOrder/orderResults/Orders/itemResults/Items') as T(C)

    END
    DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 1
```

Comment: Which database server?